# Mocking a global scope class function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, mockery

i'm facing the following issue :

i have to mock the function [get_result()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) from [\WP_User_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/)

but phpunit throw an error with this statement :

`Error: Call to undefined method WP_User_Query::get_results()`

i use to mock WordPress functions with WP_Mock and Mockery with success , any idea ?
here is my test function and the original code (i scrapped unecessary code) :

```
public function testMigrateSooUserAccount()
{
    // variables
    $id = 1;
    // mocked objects
    $user = Mockery::mock('user');        
    $users = Mockery::mock('\WP_User_Query');
    $user->ID = $id;

    $users->shouldReceive('get_results')->with()->andReturn([1]);
    $role = new \Core\Users\Role;
    $return = $role->migrate_soo_user_account($user->ID);
    self::assertTrue($return);
}
```

the original code :

```
public function migrate_soo_user_account($user_id) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $email = $user_info->user_email;
    $email = explode("@", $email);
    $users = new \WP_User_Query( array(  // the global scope class mocked
        'search'         => '*'.esc_attr( $email[0]).'*',
        'search_columns' => array(
            'user_email',
        ),
        'orderby'=>'user_registered',
        ) );
        $users_found = $users->get_results(); // that function seems undefined 
        $newrole='';
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

so i solved this issue by declaring WP_User_Query as a class inside my test file and then mocking it